# Does Jessica Jones have any issues from her treatment?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, jessica-jones-2015, jessica-jones

We know that the experiments done on Jessica can potentially lead to psychological issues, notably in the case of

> her mother

who exhibited severe anger management issues or even dissociative episodes.

The "Whizzer" also had psychological issues, which could *possibly* be attributed to the treatment, too.

Jessica occasionally seems to have some anger management problems (see: her court-ordered sessions).

She also is apparently dependent on alcohol, and even has started experiencing some hallucinations when under great stress.

On the other hand, we know Jessica has PTSD, of which alcoholism and even hallucinations *can* be symptoms. And her anger could just be normal for someone who has so much to deal with.

Does Jessica exhibit any psychological effects (not necessarily anger issues) from the experimental treatment used on her? Or can it all be attributed to her individual experiences?

Comment: I've not finished watching S2 yet, but we do see some of young Jessica, and prior to the traumatic events that follow, she seemed a bit more well-adjusted (she's drinking, but doesn't seem to be an alcoholic and is at least initially trying to finish school).

Comment: Drinking :p * *coughs* *

Comment: None that I saw that couldn't eqaully be explained by developing powers in puberty, having a somewhat abusive foster-parent..oh yeah, and being raped and controlled by a psychopath! If she did have issues caused by the "treatment"...it would be hard to pick them out!

Comment: @Paulie_D - I agree, but at the same time it also seems possible that, like the other test subjects, she might have experienced some mental changes - maybe even just now manifesting.

Comment: I think they explicitly say in S2 thaheshe had power and was ok and only after killgrave she looses it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Probably not**

One recurring theme in the series is that Jessica Jones is psychologically broken and is barely surviving. She says something like

> It took a dead coming back to show me that I was dead too.

late in Season 2. This could be a consequence of her treatment but the most likely explanation is that she has PTSD due to her past traumatic experiences (**spoilers**):

1. Being mentally controlled by a psychopath and sexually abused by him.
2. In particular, killing a woman under his influence.
3. Having to shot her lover (Luke Cage).
4. An abusive adoptive mother.
5. Losing her family in a car accident. It is explicitly mentioned in the second season that she feels guilty for the accident as her father was looking at her and not the road at the moment of the accident.

That's a lot for one person.

The difference between Jessica and Alisa, her mother, is that Alisa's injuries were more severe, and she had to follow a heavier treatment, to the point that her physical appearance changed. Doctor Malus also explains that she had to be put on induced coma after each treatment and that long comas can have consequences on the brain. Here is  a quote from Karl Malus in the seventh episode of Season 2 "AKA I want your cray cray" (taken from [the MCU wikia](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Alisa_Jones))

> Dr. Malus: "When we got you, you were pretty much a goner. We had to induce a coma after each treatment to manage the side effects. But the way you've come through it... it's mind-blowing."
>
> Alisa Jones: "Come through what, exactly?"
>
> Dr. Malus: "Cutting-edge genetic editing. It stimulates healing through cell regeneration."

In addition, Alisa explained in a later episode that Jessica's relational difficulties are not due to her accident, but that she was a loner even before the accident.

Comment: It might be worth to add, that Jessica is terrified of driving a car since her accident - she never even tried making a licence.